# Unable to change sort order for emails listed using Microsoft365R

Tags: r, email, microsoft365r

Using library Microsoft365R I can list the mails but it is always from the oldest and I can't figure out how to change it to list the latest mail first.

The below is the example code I am using and trying to sort by **received desc** and **received asc** gives the same output. Also listed 300 mails to show that there are more than 100 mails so the first 2 listings should have different max/min received dates

I am expecting the desc and asc to give different mails or if the number of mails is small it should be in a different order.

```
#Load library
library(Microsoft365R)

#setup environment
outlb <- get_business_outlook()

#by = "received desc"
mails_desc <- outlb$list_emails(by = "received desc",filter = "startswith(sender/emailAddress/address,'test@microsoft.com')", n = 100)

#by = "received asc"
mails_asc <- outlb$list_emails(by = "received asc",filter = "startswith(sender/emailAddress/address,'test@microsoft.com')", n = 100)

#listed 300 to show there are more than 100 emails
mails_300 <- outlb$list_emails(filter = "startswith(sender/emailAddress/address,'test@microsoft.com')", n = 300)
```

Output showing the min/max receivedDateTime

> #by = "received desc"

> mails_desc[[1]]$properties$receivedDateTime
> [1] "**2022-02-21T03:10:17Z**"
> mails_desc[[100]]$properties$receivedDateTime
> [1] "**2022-05-03T00:27:23Z**"

> #by = "received asc"

> mails_asc[[1]]$properties$receivedDateTime
> [1] "**2022-02-21T03:10:17Z**"
> mails_asc[[100]]$properties$receivedDateTime
> [1] "**2022-05-03T00:27:23Z**"

> #listed 300 to show there are more than 100 emails

> mails_300[[1]]$properties$receivedDateTime
> [1] "**2022-02-21T03:10:17Z**"
> mails_300[[300]]$properties$receivedDateTime
> [1] "**2022-09-26T01:28:59Z**"